# I can't see the result of EntityGraph. Is it still working?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, entity

I tried to check how EntityGraph works in java ee, but after trying many options and various Persistence Provider, I did not see the result of its work. I tried lazily loading related entities and regular entity fields, but everything worked as usual. If it really works, could you give an example where it really has an effect?

first entity:

```java
@Entity
public class Students {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    String name;
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    String surname;
    @OneToMany
    List<StudInfos> studInfos = new ArrayList<>();
    public Students() {}
    public Students(String name, String surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setStudInfos(StudInfos studInfos) {
        this.studInfos.add(studInfos);
    }
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
}
```

second entity:

```java
@Entity
public class StudInfos {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    int id;
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    String address;
    @OneToOne
    Students students;
    public StudInfos() {}
    public StudInfos(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public void setStudents(Students students) {
        this.students = students;
    }
}
```

main class:
When trying to output fields (which were loaded lazily) after closing EntityManager, they are calmly output and an error is not thrown, as if they were already loaded.

```java
public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
                .createEntityManagerFactory("studentUnit");

        Students students = new Students("Andres", "Kenzi");
        StudInfos infos = new StudInfos("dfsiodfdsj");
        StudInfos infos1 = new StudInfos("dfsiodddddd");
        students.setStudInfos(infos);
        students.setStudInfos(infos1);
        EntityManager manager = emf.createEntityManager();
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        manager.persist(students);
        manager.persist(infos);
        manager.persist(infos1);
        manager.getTransaction().commit();

        Query query = manager.createQuery("Select s from Students s where s.id = 1");
        EntityGraph<Students> eg = manager.createEntityGraph(Students.class);
        eg.addAttributeNodes("name");
        query.setHint("javax.persistence.loadgraph", eg);
        Students students1 = (Students) query.getSingleResult();

        manager.close();
        emf.close();
        System.out.println(students1.studInfos.get(0).getAddress());
        System.out.println(students1.getSurname());
    }
}
```

Comment: Turn on SQL logging and if it is working, it should affect the SQL and when SQL is issued. The load graph though should have no effect - LoadGraph is used to mark 'name' as eager, which it already is, and everything else left to their defaults. What do you mean you've tried various Persistence Provider? Lazy loading basics in hibernate I believe requires bytecode enhancement.